# Formatting datetime pt-BR in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm needing to print a datetime format in Portuguese in Brazil. In doing:

```
puts access.date.strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y, %H:%M h")
```

The print console:

```
Sunday, 16 de August de 2015, 08:56 h
```

However, the correct would be:

```
Domingo, 16 de Agosto de 2015, 08:56 h
```

I edited my application.rb:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :'pt-BR'
config.i18n.available_locales = :'pt-BR'
```

And I created the en-BR.yml file:

```
pt-BR:
  breadcrumbs:
    application:
      root: Início
    pages:
      pages: Paginas
  helpers:
    actions: Ações
    links:
      back: Voltar
      cancel: Cancelar
      confirm: Você tem certeza?
      destroy: Apagar
      new: Novo
      edit: Editar
    titles:
      edit: Editar %{model}
      save: Salvar %{model}
      new: Novo %{model}
      delete: Apagar %{model}

  # formatos de data e hora
    date:
      formats:
        default: "%d/%m/%Y"
        short: "%d de %B"
        long: "%d de %B de %Y"

      day_names: [Domingo, Segunda, Terça, Quarta, Quinta, Sexta, Sábado]
      abbr_day_names: [Dom, Seg, Ter, Qua, Qui, Sex, Sáb]
      month_names: [~, Janeiro, Fevereiro, Março, Abril, Maio, Junho, Julho, Agosto, Setembro, Outubro, Novembro, Dezembro]
      abbr_month_names: [~, Jan, Fev, Mar, Abr, Mai, Jun, Jul, Ago, Set, Out, Nov, Dez]
      order: [day, month, year]

    time:
      formats:
        default: "%A, %d de %B de %Y, %H:%M h"
        short: "%d/%m, %H:%M h"
        long: "%A, %d de %B de %Y, %H:%M h"
      am: ''
      pm: ''
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use the rails own helper `I18n.localize` or its shorthand `l`. You also need to define your format in locales (already present in your case):

```
 pt-BR:
   date:
     formats:
       default: "%A, %d de %B de %Y, %H:%M h"
       short: "%d/%m, %H:%M h"
       long: "%A, %d de %B de %Y, %H:%M h"
```

Notice that these translations are direct children of `pt-BR`, not of `helpers` as in your case. Then use

```
I18n.l(access.date, format: :long)
```

Comment: Hello, I think you did not understand my need. I need to print "Domingo, Agosto 16, 2015, 08:56 h" and not "Sunday, 16 August 2015, 08:56 h." I want to print the weekday and the month name in Portuguese rather than English.

Comment: Using this technique, that's [exactly what I get](https://gist.github.com/panmari/8edf62a3539c3bc17e5b).

Comment: I realized your yml keys are a bit mixed up, 'date' and 'time' should not be child to 'helpers'. I edited my answer to be a bit more clear about the structure.